# how can i use a particular UIActionSheet's button with some actioning (explain in brief) in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can i use a particular UIActionSheet's button with some actioning (explain in brief) in iphone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the UIActionSheetDelegate protocol. The method you are looking for is the

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

You have to check for the buttonIndex and then you can do whatever you want.